# jquery thumbnail gallery to use multiple times on a page

Tags: jquery

I wrote a basic thumbnail gallery but was wondering if you could do something similar so you can use multiple times on a page?

```
$(".thumb-box a").click( function() {
var changeSrc = $(this).attr("href");
var changeText = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
var title = $(this).attr('title');
$("#bigpic img").attr("src", changeSrc);
$("#caption").html(changeText);
$("#text").html(title);
return false;
});
```

snippet :

```js
$(".thumb-box a").click( function() {
var changeSrc = $(this).attr("href");
var changeText = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
var title = $(this).attr('title');
$("#bigpic img").attr("src", changeSrc);
$("#caption").html(changeText);
$("#text").html(title);
return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns small-12">
<div id="bigpic">
<picture><img alt="pic1 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></picture>
</div>
<span class="text-element image-caption" id="caption">Image caption</span>
</div>

<div class="columns small-12">
<p class="paragraph image-text text-center" id="text">Changing description text</p>
<div class="container thumb-box">
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="responsive-picture thumb-pic" title="pic1 title"><picture><img alt="pic1 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></picture></a>
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="responsive-picture thumb-pic" title="pic2 title"><picture><img alt="pic2 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></picture></a>
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="responsive-picture thumb-pic" title="pic3 title"><picture><img alt="pic3 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></picture></a>
</div>
<div class="container thumb-box">
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="responsive-picture thumb-pic" title="pic4 title"><picture><img alt="pic4 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></picture></a>
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="responsive-picture thumb-pic" title="pic5 title"><picture><img alt="pic5 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></picture></a>
<a href="http://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="responsive-picture thumb-pic" title="pic6 title"><picture><img alt="pic6 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></picture></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the code multiple times on the same page, the first thing you'll need to do is update your HTML to use classes instead of IDs, since IDs must be unique. So `$("#caption").html(changeText);` becomes `$(".caption").html(changeText);` in your jQuery.

Then you can update your functions so that instead of modifying the HTML of every element with the `caption` class, you only update the `.caption` elements that are descendants of the wrapper we're working within. That will allow you to use this script for multiple galleries per page.

For example, instead of `$(".caption").html(changeText)`, you can use `$(this).closest('.columns').prev('.columns').find('.caption').html(changeCaption);` to refer to the specific caption in that particular gallery (where `$(this)` is `$(".thumb-box a")`).

Here's a snippet with the gallery HTML repeated three times, to demonstrate this idea. [And here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh71Lm5r/8/).

```js
$('.thumb-box a').click(function() {
  var changeSrc = $(this).attr('href');
  var changeCaption = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
  var changeText = $(this).attr('title');
  $(this).closest('.columns').prev('.columns').find('.bigpic img').attr("src", changeSrc);
  $(this).closest('.columns').prev('.columns').find('.caption').html(changeCaption);
  $(this).closest('.columns').find('.text').html(changeText);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.bigpic-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.big-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span.image-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: auto;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  border: .0625rem solid #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns small-12">
  <div class="bigpic-box">
    <div class="bigpic" class="bigpic">
      <picture><img alt="pic1 alt" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=1"></picture>
    </div>
    <span class="image-caption caption">Changing caption</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns small-12">
  <p class="paragraph image-text text-center text">Changing text</p>
  <div class="container thumb-box">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=1%20top" class="thumb-pic" title="pic1 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic1 alt" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=1t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=2%20top" class="thumb-pic" title="pic2 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic2 alt" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=2t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=3%20top" class="thumb-pic" title="pic3 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic3 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=3t"></picture>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container thumb-box">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=4%20top" class="thumb-pic" title="pic4 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic4 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=4t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=5%20top" class="thumb-pic" title="pic5 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic5 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=5t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=6%20top" class="thumb-pic" title="pic6 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic6 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=6t"></picture>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns small-12">
  <div class="bigpic-box">
    <div class="bigpic" class="bigpic">
      <picture><img alt="pic1 alt" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=1"></picture>
    </div>
    <span class="image-caption caption">Changing caption</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns small-12">
  <p class="paragraph image-text text-center text">Changing text</p>
  <div class="container thumb-box">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=1%20mid" class="thumb-pic" title="pic1 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic1 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=1t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=2%20mid" class="thumb-pic" title="pic2 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic2 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=2t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=3%20mid" class="thumb-pic" title="pic3 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic3 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=3t"></picture>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container thumb-box">
    <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=4%20mid" class="thumb-pic" title="pic4 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic4 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=4t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=5%20mid" class="thumb-pic" title="pic5 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic5 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=5t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=6%20mid" class="thumb-pic" title="pic6 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic6 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=6t"></picture>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns small-12">
  <div class="bigpic-box">
    <div class="bigpic" class="bigpic">
      <picture><img alt="pic1 alt" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=1"></picture>
    </div>
    <span class="image-caption caption">Changing caption</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns small-12">
  <p class="paragraph image-text text-center text">Changing text</p>
  <div class="container thumb-box">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=1%20bot" class="thumb-pic" title="pic1 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic1 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=1t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=2%20bot" class="thumb-pic" title="pic2 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic2 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=2t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=3%20bot" class="thumb-pic" title="pic3 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic3 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=3t"></picture>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container thumb-box">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=4%20bot" class="thumb-pic" title="pic4 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic4 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=4t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=5%20bot" class="thumb-pic" title="pic5 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic5 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=5t"></picture>
    </a>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=6%20bot" class="thumb-pic" title="pic6 title">
      <picture><img alt="pic6 alt" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=6t"></picture>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that part of the problem we were having with text not changing was due to the fact that your captions and changing text had two different `class` attributes. For example, your changing text looked like this:

```
<p class="paragraph image-text text-center" class="text">Changing text</p>
```

In that case, the second `class` attribute won't get picked up. But since `.text` was the class we were targeting in our jQuery, that meant the script didn't work. In order to fix this, simply combine all the classes into a single attribute, like this:

```
<p class="paragraph image-text text-center text">Changing text</p>
```

Comment: Doesn't change the text at least in the snippet, but the problem is more the large image is relative in one column with the caption absolute that positions to that container, which is responsive. The paragraph in another column with the thumbs so I can't wrap it all. I guess I'll just have to use multiple scripts.

Comment: @Gord Sorry, the problem about the script not working was due to the placeholder images being served from http while Stack Overflow is on https. Recent browser updates are starting to block insecure content served to secure websites, but I guess the browser I was using when I wrote this hasn't updated to include that change yet, so it was working there. As for your other concerns, if you can post more HTML in your question that demonstrates the overall structure, I can see about updating this answer so you can use the function twice without adding a wrapper.

Comment: Hey no prob I appreciate the help. I had it in a fiddle to start with so let's go back there   http://jsfiddle.net/bh71Lm5r/3/

Comment: @Gord Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/bh71Lm5r/4/. I just took the HTML you had and repeated it three times, no added wrappers or anything. If it looks good, I will update this answer. If not, you will need to update your question with HTML that demonstrates what your markup would look like with multiple sets of big pictures/thumbnails on a single page, so I can see what the deal is.

Comment: I just tried something similar but it only does the images, not the caption and text. I messed mine up though by trying to use the .closest image-caption class etc and then tried a function(index) wrapper too... Got to be a way you'd think?

Comment: @Gord I'm sure there's probably a way, but like I said, without seeing your HTML, it's impossible to say. I'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: LOL well this is the live test http://gordw.com/rsd/test/index.html but I changed the script a bit since I posted that... I'm trying to write something to help other as well as you can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157764/discussion-between-cjl750-and-gord).